# Citrix Server sort of app - on a Mac?

Tags: macos, citrix

Does anyone know of a similar product to Citrix Server that'll run on the Mac OS?

Essentially, I'm looking to allow multiple remote users to log in to the same OSX Server at the same time (with full visual desktop, not SSH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone have experience with [Aqua Connect](http://www.aquaconnect.net/?page_id=26)? Found them from Google, and they claim the next version works on RDP as well as VNC. Wondering if it's just a nice wrapper around the VNC capabilities `@Soeren Kuklau` pointed out.

Thanks for the link to Vine Server, that's worth investigating.

Answer (score 8):

OS X's Quartz window server has no remoting abilities, unlike [its predecessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_PostScript). X11 *does*, but 'native' OS X applications don't use that; of the few Mac apps typically run in X11 (such as GIMP or CrossOver), none are specific to the Mac, so you might as well run them on a different OS.

That said, if all you want is to visually remote-control a session, it is possible to use VNC or a derivative, such as Apple Remote Desktop. Since 10.4, this allows for multiple simultaneous sessions, [as implemented with Vine Server](http://www.redstonesoftware.com/products/vine_viewer/multidesktop). Remote Desktop also has other abilities such as remotely installing and updating software.

(Unlike Citrix and X11, VNC does *not* send drawing commands over the network; it instead transmits a compressed image representation pixel-per-pixel.)

You should specify your exact needs. **You will not get a Citrix-like experience where you can run single Mac apps in their own remote session.** You will, however, get remote graphical control, and that *may* be more than enough for you.

Comment: iChat screen sharing - http://www.apple.com/macosx/features/ichat.html

Apple Remote Desktop - http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/

Back to My Mac - http://www.apple.com/mobileme/features/mac.html

Screen Sharing from Finder - http://www.apple.com/macosx/features/300.html#finder

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of it, but [from their blog](http://www.aquaconnect.net/?p=170):

> Aqua Connect Terminal Server uses the VNC (Virtual Network Computing) protocol to send data between Mac OS X and the client application.

Now, if someone *does* know of a non-VNC solution, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

John Vasileff,

Back to My Mac is a tunnelling / NAT traversal technique that enables the use of any networking (including VNC-based remote control). iChat screen sharing, Finder Screen Sharing and Remote Desktop all use VNC. Apple does not offer any non-VNC solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[Citrix XenDesktop iPhone Demo](http://citrixblogger.org/2008/09/08/citrix-iphone-xendesktop-demo/)